# Django - leaving blank form when session doesn't exist

Tags: django, forms, session

I have a noobie question about filling registration forms from sessions. I have 3 step registration form that saves data to session. I am trying to fill form data with previous answers when user goes step back. I managed to do that, but now I have problem when session is empty. Here is the problematic code:

```
    if request.session['form_data_page_1']:
        korisnik = Forma1(initial=request.session['form_data_page_1'])
    else:
         korisnik = Forma1()
```

when I do that I keep getting 'KeyError at /start/dadilja/1/' - 'form_data_page_1'. I also tried to do something like this:

```
    if request.session['form_data_page_1'] is not Null:
        korisnik = Forma1(initial=request.session['form_data_page_1'])
    else:
         korisnik = Forma1()
```

and something like this:

```
try: 
    korisnik = Forma1(initial=request.session['form_data_page_1'])
except:
    korisnik = Forma1()
```

but when I do that, I get blank page with submit button on it. How to do this correctly, to get blank form when session is empty, and filled form with session data when session exist? Thanks in advance.

Renato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions implement a dictionary interface, so you can use `.get` which returns None if the key is not found.

```
korisnik = Forma1(initial=request.session.get('form_data_page_1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

When you try to get a key from dictionary using `request.session['form_data_page_1']` and key is not present in dictionary then it gives you the key error. So first check key present or not 
 by using `request.session.get('form_data_page_1')` it's return None if key is not present and if key is present then it return value.

```
if request.session.get('form_data_page_1'):
    korisnik = Forma1(initial=request.session['form_data_page_1'])
else:
    korisnik = Forma1()
```

Hope this is helps you

Comment: Thank you. Now i get page without form and with only submit button. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly your `Forma1()` return? If it is return a blank form so that your template does not get a form and it's showing blank.

Comment: Problem was in my html template, it works now. Thanks!